# Showing that this sequence is increasing for $n\ge 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

I have the following sequence $\left \{k \sin \left(\frac{1}{k}\right) \right\}^{\infty}_{1}$. I don't know how to show that this is monotonically increasing.

I tried taking the derivative of the corresponding function $f(x) = x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$, and show that $f^{\prime} \geq 0$ for $x \geq 1$, but the derivative is kind of messy. The problem falls down to showing that $$\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - \frac{\cos{\frac{1}{x}}}{x} \geq 0.$$

I am open to other approaches too, maybe some outside the box thinking way that doesn't even need the first derivative. But it feels like one should be able to show that the inequality holds.
Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this just a matter of using that $\sin(\epsilon)=\epsilon-\epsilon^3/3!+O(\epsilon^5)$ for small $\epsilon$?

Comment: Do you know the (rather classical) function "cardinal sine", written sinc and defined by sinc$(x):=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ if $x \ne 0$ and sinc $0 := 1$ ? Your sequence can be written sinc$\frac{1}{k}$. Moreover sinc in a decreasing function on interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JeanMarie It's a course equivalent to calculus 2. But obviously your solution would have been smooth.

Comment: @thedude My friend thought of that, but i couldn't get my way around it since we wanna show that it is for all x >= 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$\sin\frac1x-\frac1x\cos\frac1x\ge0\iff\tan\frac1x\ge\frac1x$$

Put now $\;t:=\frac1x\;$, so that you want to find about

$$f(t):=\tan t-t\;,\;\;f'(t)=\frac1{\cos^2t}-1\ge0\;\;\forall t\;\Bbb R-\left\{\frac\pi2+k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\right\}$$

Comment: Thanks, but how does this show that $\tan x  - x \geq 0 $ for $x \geq 1$?

Comment: If you take only $\;t\ge0\;$, then since $\;f(0)=0\;$ and the function is monotone ascending in $\;\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)\;$, then $\;f(t)\ge0\;$ ... Observe that in order to do the above we must eliminate the points $\;t=\frac\pi2+k\pi\;$, where $\;\tan t\;$ isn't defined. But this is not problem in your case since you're interested in $\;\frac1x\;,\;\;x>0\;$ ...!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to look at the function $g(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and show that it is decreasing on $(0,1)$ (notice that $f(x)=g(1/x)$). You have
$$
g'(x)=\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}
$$
and the numerator is negative, since $x<\tan x$ on $(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: So by the negation of $g(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is decreasing on (0,1), we get that f(x) is increasing on the complement of (0,1)?

Comment: @PhysicistNumber73 $g$ being decreasing on $(0,1)$ is equivalent to $f$ being increasing on $(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

*Without derivatives*

$$a_k=k \sin \left(\frac{1}{k}\right) \quad \implies \quad \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=
\frac{k+1}{k} \sin \left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right) \csc \left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$ If $k$ is large, by Taylor

$$\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=1+\frac{1}{3 k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$